# C pointer operator: attach to function or data type?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, return-value, heap-memory

After years of mucking about with Linux and being very interested in low-level computer design & programming (but no spare time), I am finally beginning my journey to learning C. I am working through B Kernighan & D Ritchie's C Programming Language (v2) book, as well as through the C language track at exercism.io

The first task in both is the quintessential Hello World program. In K&R, the task set is to *print* "Hello World" using the `stdio.h` library. All well and good. In the exercism version, the task set is to *return* "Hello, World!". The tutorial-provided hello_world.c file contains skeleton code to be completed; it (truncated, and completed by me) looks like this:

`#include <stddef.h>
const char *hello(void) {
   return "Hello, World!";
}`

Based on everything I've read on C so far, it's not really standard to return a string, but that's OK too. After a bit of fussing and one segmentation fault (core dumped) (I tried to return the function itself: `return hello();`, no bueno), I got the tests to pass.

I've learned that the `*` character is a *pointer operator*, and it allows the function to return a pointer to the memory address of the character array (I think), which is pretty cool. So, it made sense to me to have the pointer operator superscripting the *function name*. However, in the majority of Q&A and tutorial websites, the pointer operator is shown superscripting the *data declaration* `char` instead. [This](https://flaviocopes.com/c-return-string/) link, in particular, shows there are three viable options for placement of the pointer operator, and states that they are all equivalent.

When I began writing this question, I thought that attaching the pointer operator to the function name made the most sense - that's where the character array would be in memory, right? With further thought, it makes more sense that the pointer operator should be attached to the data declaration `char`, because really it's the *output of the function*, the address of the *data* on the heap, that's being returned, not the function itself (which I think is on the stack).

My question: **is there a difference between the three placement options for the pointer operator?** If yes, what are they? If no, what is best practice?

Comment: I tried to return the function itself: return hello(); -- If the ``hello()`` definition here is what you have mentioned, then you are not returning the function (pointer). You are returning the result of that function which is ``const char*`` (first the function gets evaluated before returning)

Comment: it allows the function to return a pointer to the memory address of the character array-- Well, it depends on which variable you are de-referencing (``*``). For getting the memory address of character array you should be de-referencing a pointer to char array

Comment: So, it made sense to me to have the pointer operator superscripting the function name -- No it has nothing to do with any de-referencing operations. In c function has declaration and definition (there you are declaring and defining at the same it). You are just saying that this function returns ``const char*`` no de-referencing happens at that point

Comment: The process of compiling (behaves like) splits the source code into *tokens*. No whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, ...) is ever part of a *token* (except string literals), so all variations of `char * foo` are split to `<type_token> <operator_token> <identifier_token>` which is what ultimately gets compiled. Whitespace is mostly beneficial for humans, not compilers.

Comment: @pmg this makes sense. I was thinking that the precompilation processing for `const char func()`--> `<keyword token><type token><func token>` would be different with the pointer operator modifying the thing it's attached to: `const char* func` --> `<keyword token><*modified char token><func token>`  versus `<keyword token><char token><*modified func>`  but if I understand you correctly, the pointer operator isn't modifying the char token, it's just being included in the sequence of tokens?   Would `const * char func()` be any different, or for that matter `* const char func()` ?

Comment: hmm ... the process of tokenization does not care. It simply reads characters (as many as possible) until it cannot make a token. `char const*` or `const char*` is 3 tokens; `x--` is 2 tokens; `x---y` is 4 tokens (`x`, `--`, `-`, and `y`); `x- --y` is 4 tokens.

Comment: re `const`... `const` is a little bit special: it applies to what is on its left unless it doesn't exist (or doesn't make sense) in which case it applies to what is on its right. In both `char const *p` and `const char *p` the const applies to the char (the contents of `p`)

Comment: @pmg that helps, thanks. Someone else linked a related answer that did the trick, and this link was very helpful also: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/amp/

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* myName()
const char * myName()
const char *myName()
```

no difference at all